# foldLeft on Map - Why does that work?

Tags: scala, foldleft

This is from a Coursera course, until now no one could help me.
The following works, taken from a lecture.

```
object polynomials {

  class Poly(terms0: Map[Int, Double]) {

    def this(bindings: (Int, Double)*) = this(bindings.toMap)

    val terms = terms0 withDefaultValue 0.0

    def +(other: Poly) = new Poly((other.terms foldLeft terms)(addTerm))

    def addTerm(terms: Map[Int, Double], term: (Int, Double)) : Map[Int, Double]= {
      val (exp, coeff) = term
      terms + (exp -> (coeff + terms(exp)))
    }

    override def toString =
      (for ((exp, coeff) <- terms.toList.sorted.reverse)
        yield coeff+"x^"+exp) mkString " + "
  }

  val p1 = new Poly(1 -> 2.0, 3 -> 4.0, 5 -> 6.2)
  val p2 = new Poly(0 -> 3.0, 3 -> 7.0)
  p1 + p2

  p1.terms(7)

}
```

Considering that the signature of `foldLeft` in `Map` is as follows,

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, (A, B)) => B): B
```

I try to understand the signature and map it to the usage in above example.

The zero element `z` corresponds to `terms` so the type would be `Map[Int, Double]`.
The operator `op` corresponds to `addTerm` which has the signature `( Map[Int, Double], (Int, Double) ) => Map[Int, Double]`.

To me this does not look consistent. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the issue [SI-6974](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6947) related to Scaladoc, which seems to be fixed in Scala 2.12-RC1. You can check nightly [Scala 2.12.x](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/nightly/2.12.x/api/2.12.x/scala/collection/Map.html#foldLeft[B](z:B)(op:(B,A)=>B):B) API docs, it shows correct signature.

### Explanation:

The signature of `foldLeft` defined in [TraversableOnce](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce) is

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) ⇒ B): B
```

where `A` is a type of collection and comes from `Traversable[A]`.

`Map[A, B] <: Traversable[(A, B)]`, then in the definition of `foldLeft` scaladoc just substitutes type `A` of collection with `(A, B)`, which brings confusion:

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, (A, B)) ⇒ B): B
```

If you rename parameters of the map to `Map[K, V]`, then `foldLeft` becomes:

```
 def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, (K, V)) ⇒ B): B
```

Comment: In the REPL, autocomplete of `Map(1->"one").foldLeft` yields `def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, (Int, String)) => B): B` which might help diagnose it.